# How to get the conditions required to analyze the result?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization, symbolic-computation

I'm struggling to understand the method followed in the following analysis. Can someone please explain, how the author got the values of $Δ_1$ and $K_1$ and justify its analysis.

[image]

I have tried to isolate "$Δ$" and "$K$" by setting Equation (B8) equal to zero. But I have failed to get the similar conditions.

P.S: I'm new to mathematical modelling, so I really need to understand whats going on here. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect this will be nearly impossible without at least knowing some of the assumptions about $\beta$.